# Boto with py2exe

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, py2exe, boto

I am using Python 2.7, Boto 2.6, and py2exe to create a windows executable that interacts with Amazon's Dynamodb.  The application compiles using py2exe but hangs indefinitely whenever interacting with any AWS.

Here is my setup.py for py2exe

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys

setup(windows=[{"script" : "smart_gui.py"}],
 options={"py2exe" : {
 "includes" : ["sip", "PyQt4", "simplejson", "email","lxml","http", "urllib",
 "email"], 
 "packages":["gzip", "email"],
 "excludes":["Carbon","_scproxy", "Carbon.Files"]}})
```

And this line causes the program to hand indefinitely.

```
table = self.dynamo.get_table(self.conf['users_table'])
```

Here is the relevent output of py2exe

```
The following modules appear to be missing
['Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath', 'builtins', 'cchardet', 'certifi', 'email.Charset',
'email.Encoders', 'email.Errors', 'email.Generator', 'email.Header',
'email.Iterators', 'email.MIMEAudio', 'email.MIMEBase', 'email.MIMEImage',
'email.MIMEMessage', 'email.MIMEMultipart', 'email.MIMEText', 'email.Message', 
'email.Parser', 'email.Utils', 'email.base64MIME', 'email.quopriMIME', 'http.client',
'http.cookiejar', 'http.cookies', 'kerberos', 'oauthlib.common', 'oauthlib.oauth1', 
'oauthlib.oauth1.rfc5849', 'packages.ssl_match_hostname.CertificateError', 
'packages.ssl_match_hostname.match_hostname', 'queue', 'simplejson._speedups', 
'test.test_support', 'urllib.parse', 'urllib.request']

Make sure you have the license if you distribute any of them, and
make sure you don't distribute files belonging to the operating system.

OLEAUT32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
USER32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
MSVCP90.dll - C:\Users\karl\Desktop\Smart_Select\MSVCP90.dll
SHELL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
KERNEL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
WINMM.dll - C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
COMDLG32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\COMDLG32.dll
ADVAPI32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
NETAPI32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\NETAPI32.dll
WS2_32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
WINSPOOL.DRV - C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
GDI32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
IMM32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.dll
VERSION.dll - C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
ole32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
ntdll.dll - C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
```

How can I get Boto to work with py2exe?

Answer (score 1):

I spent most of a day on this - py2app wraps up all the dependencies into a site-packages.zip, and boto tries to read its cacerts.txt directly from the zip archive (treating it like a directory, which won't work).

I'm not clear on what (if any) runtime unzipping magic py2app does, but the easiest solution I had was to make my own copy of cacerts.txt, include that as a datafile in the py2app setup.py:

```
DATA_FILES = [                                                                                                                              
#Add the cert                                                                                                                           
('backup_cacert', ['cacerts.txt'])                                                                                                      
]
```

then in my main function do something like:

```
import boto.connection                                                                                                                      
try:                                                                                                                                        
    open(boto.connection.DEFAULT_CA_CERTS_FILE)                                                                                             
except IOError as e:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    boto.connection.DEFAULT_CA_CERTS_FILE = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'backup_cacert', 'cacerts.txt')                                                                                                    
try:                                                                                                                                        
    open(boto.connection.DEFAULT_CA_CERTS_FILE)                                                                                             
except IOError as e:                                                                                                                        
    raise e
```